# how to get Heading direction from raw IMU Data?

Tags: c, signals, imu

I have some raw data which accelerated and rotated in each axis(x, y, z). but I don't know what axis is gravity direction. Depends on each object, I can't figure out which direction the IMU is installed. Sometimes the x-axis is the direction of gravity, sometimes the y-axis, sometimes the z-axis and sometimes not all.

I need to find out when the object(with the IMU mounted) is moving at 1m/s^2 in Heading direction.
If the Z-axis is the direction of gravity and the x-axis is the direction of motion, the IMU needs to find a value with an Ax value of 1m/s^2 or more(If IMU installed oriented like the image below).

[image]

-img1

But I don't know which direction is the direction of motion and which is the direction of gravity. Therefore, I want to find out which direction is the moving direction through 3 acceleration signals and 3 gyro signals.

[image]

Even if the sensor is installed at an angle as shown in Figure 2, what should be done to find out that the sensor is moving with an acceleration of 1m/s^2 in the moving direction? I need to code in C. Since there is not enough computing margin in the my embedded environment, implementation should be as simple as possible. Is there any good solution ?